# Are there ever job openings that say "Only M.S. degrees apply", and if so, will an M.Eng. still cut it?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, employment

If these exist, then I would imagine they are in research. Is an M.Eng. looked as favorably upon as an M.S.?

Comment: It depends on whgere you are. There are countries where there is no M. Eng degrees awarded (but rather a slightly cryptic M.Sc. Eng. which is both and none of the above)

Comment: Career and education questions like this are off-topic for the site.

Comment: @AndyT then where do they go? Can't you answer my question?

Comment: @joojaa That doesn't answer my question at all. I think the implication is I live in the United States.

Comment: @masque its not an answer, and nobody can answer that question it depends on many other factors than just country. You can not assume that the location is United states on the internet that has to read in your question! If not it will probably not get answered.  In any case stackexchange is not a good place for career advice like this because they have practically no value, are subjective and are of limited value over time. If you can make your question less conversational then maybe workplace might be able to take it, but don't count on it.

Comment: @joojaa Well certainly someone with years of industry experience can answer if *sometimes* there are job openings where you need a masters of science. Also, whether a Masters of Engineering still applies.

Comment: @masque yes but your asking to prove the negative. Its true if they can find a example where its required. But if there is not then the answer can not be answered. But yes i know of this happening outside US due to there not being a degree in M. Eng.

Comment: @masque - There is no implication that you are in the US. There are lots of people on the internet from outside the US. Some of them even speak English. I'm one of them. As to where these questions go: not on stackexchange, I'm afraid. Yahoo answers would accept these questions.

Comment: It's going to depend on so many factors. The details of the MS/MSE/MEng program, the details of the job, the company and so on and on and on. I have worked in the USA as an engineer for almost 20 years in a variety of industries for a number of employers and I can tell you that I have never seen a job description that discriminated between a MS and a M Eng or a MSE. Some might go so far as to say Masters degree preferred, but that's about it. Personally, I've had my MS Eng degree since 2009 and never once has a potential employer brought up anything like this.

Comment: This might be at home more in the Workplace Stack Exchange, but it's still not a good question.

Comment: They are clearly wanting an inferior qualification. Take your M.Eng somewhere where it's appreciated :-)  - RM -  M.E. (elec) :-)